# Running tests with EJB Container and JPA

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jpa, wildfly

I'm suffering in understanding how to properly set up tests in JUnit for EJB and JPA. I've seen advices telling to use Arquillian for the integration test, but I want to do a simple unit test.

What I have right now is a EJB with injects a Persintance Context. I run the application in Wildfly 9 and have the datasource configured there, so my persistance file looks like this:

```
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
```

Now if I added glassfish-embedded-all to my test dependencies to run the embeded EJB container and created a simple test:

```
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("target/classes"));

    EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
    TestEJb bean = (TestEJb) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/classes/TestEJb");
    assertNotNull(bean);
    assertEquals(1,bean.test());
```

Then I receive the error as the EJB contains the refence to the MyDataSource which is not known by the container. Should I create another persistance unit and pass it somehow to the EJB?

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: what is your simple test? why Arquillian is not simple? anyway you still need a data source not persistence unit, arquillian use in memory db (as jboss developer studio provide example)

Comment: Actually reading more about Arquillian persuaded me to use it. Seems flexible enough to run simple unit tests and more sophisticated IT. I'll still need to find a way to attach the debugger to the remote instance as this is failing for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you don't have an application context so the lookup is failing.  Usually for unit testing container resources you use a mock object such as mockejb.

Lots of examples out there if you search for mockejb examples.